# Different particleRotation for each particle to point to the emitter node position

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I´m developing a game using sprite kit and I´m struggling with SKEmitterNode. I have created a texture for the particles with the shape of a water drop. I want to emit particles surrounding the emitter node and with the thinner part of the drops pointing to the emitter.

I know I can change the rotation of the particles emitted by

```
particleRotation
```

But that set the same rotation for all the particles. I need a different rotation depending if they are above the emitter, on the left, on the right...

In the following image you can see what I have right now, all the drops pointing to the same direction.

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can try using the particleAction property https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/particleAction but with this many particles expect it to consume a significant amount of CPU time

Comment: Oh nice point, but If I´m not mistaken I can´t access the particles position, therefore I can´t calculate the angle to be applied for each one. Am I right?

Comment: @pdrcabrod Did you ever find a solution to this?